# Need help getting spark-cassandra-connector to work

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

I need some help getting a test application working in the spark environment using the spark cassandra connector.

First the details:

**I have created a test app in Intellij using Scala and the following code:**

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "xx.xxx.xxx.59")
                                  .set("spark.cassandra.username", "ubuntu")
                                  .set("spark.cassandra.password", "")

  val sc = new SparkContext("spark://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7077", "Season", conf)
  println("Got past the setup.")

  val ks = "test"// analytics_loadset"
  val incf =  "kv"//site_detail"

  println("Got past setting the variables.")

  val rdd = sc.cassandraTable(ks, incf)
  println(rdd.count)
  println("Got past reading the RDD.")

  println("done with test")
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

**What i get back is the following:**

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\target\scala-2.10\classes;C:\Users\JEUser\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.4\lib\scala-library.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\colt\colt\jars\colt-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.clearspring.analytics\stream\jars\stream-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.codahale.metrics\metrics-core\bundles\metrics-core-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.codahale.metrics\metrics-graphite\bundles\metrics-graphite-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.codahale.metrics\metrics-json\bundles\metrics-json-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.codahale.metrics\metrics-jvm\bundles\metrics-jvm-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-core\jars\cassandra-driver-core-2.0.4-sources.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.datastax.cassandra\cassandra-driver-core\jars\cassandra-driver-core-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.datastax.spark\spark-cassandra-connector_2.10\jars\spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.0.0-rc4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.esotericsoftware.kryo\kryo\bundles\kryo-2.21.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.esotericsoftware.minlog\minlog\jars\minlog-1.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm\reflectasm\jars\reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\bundles\jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\bundles\jackson-core-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\bundles\jackson-databind-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\jars\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.google.guava\guava\bundles\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.ning\compress-lzf\bundles\compress-lzf-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.thoughtworks.paranamer\paranamer\jars\paranamer-2.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.twitter\chill-java\jars\chill-java-0.3.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.twitter\chill_2.10\jars\chill_2.10-0.3.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\com.typesafe\config\bundles\config-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\jars\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils-core\jars\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-codec\commons-codec\jars\commons-codec-1.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-collections\commons-collections\jars\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\jars\commons-configuration-1.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-digester\commons-digester\jars\commons-digester-1.8.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-el\commons-el\jars\commons-el-1.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\jars\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-io\commons-io\jars\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-lang\commons-lang\jars\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\commons-net\commons-net\jars\commons-net-2.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\concurrent\concurrent\jars\concurrent-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\hsqldb\hsqldb\jars\hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty\bundles\netty-3.9.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\io.netty\netty-all\jars\netty-all-4.0.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\jline\jline\jars\jline-0.9.94.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\joda-time\joda-time\jars\joda-time-2.3.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\log4j\log4j\bundles\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\net.java.dev.jets3t\jets3t\jars\jets3t-0.7.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\net.sf.py4j\py4j\jars\py4j-0.8.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.ant\ant\jars\ant-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.ant\ant-launcher\jars\ant-launcher-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.cassandra\cassandra-clientutil\jars\cassandra-clientutil-2.0.9.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.cassandra\cassandra-thrift\jars\cassandra-thrift-2.0.9.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\jars\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.commons\commons-math\jars\commons-math-2.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.curator\curator-client\bundles\curator-client-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.curator\curator-framework\bundles\curator-framework-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.curator\curator-recipes\bundles\curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-client\jars\hadoop-client-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-core\jars\hadoop-core-1.0.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\jars\httpclient-4.2.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\jars\httpcore-4.2.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.mesos\mesos\jars\mesos-0.18.1-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.10\jars\spark-core_2.10-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.thrift\libthrift\jars\libthrift-0.9.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.zookeeper\zookeeper\jars\zookeeper-3.4.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-core-asl\jars\jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.codehaus.jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\jars\jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-continuation\jars\jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-http\jars\jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-io\jars\jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-jndi\jars\jetty-jndi-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-plus\jars\jetty-plus-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-security\jars\jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-server\jars\jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-servlet\jars\jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-util\jars\jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-webapp\jars\jetty-webapp-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-xml\jars\jetty-xml-8.1.14.v20131031.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.activation\orbits\javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.mail.glassfish\orbits\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.servlet\orbits\javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit\javax.transaction\orbits\javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.joda\joda-convert\jars\joda-convert-1.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.json4s\json4s-ast_2.10\jars\json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.json4s\json4s-core_2.10\jars\json4s-core_2.10-3.2.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.json4s\json4s-jackson_2.10\jars\json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.6.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.objenesis\objenesis\jars\objenesis-1.2.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.4\lib\scala-compiler.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.4\lib\scala-reflect.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scalap\jars\scalap-2.10.4.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\jars\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\jars\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\jars\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project\pyrolite\jars\pyrolite-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project.akka\akka-actor_2.10\jars\akka-actor_2.10-2.2.3-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project.akka\akka-remote_2.10\bundles\akka-remote_2.10-2.2.3-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project.akka\akka-slf4j_2.10\bundles\akka-slf4j_2.10-2.2.3-shaded-protobuf.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project.protobuf\protobuf-java\jars\protobuf-java-2.4.1-shaded.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.tachyonproject\tachyon\jars\tachyon-0.4.1-thrift.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.uncommons.maths\uncommons-maths\jars\uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\org.xerial.snappy\snappy-java\bundles\snappy-java-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\oro\oro\jars\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\JEUser\.ivy2\cache\xmlenc\xmlenc\jars\xmlenc-0.52.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\netty-3.9.0.Final.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\sbt-assembly-0.11.2.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\cassandra-driver-dse-2.0.2.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\spark-core_2.10-0.9.1.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\metrics-core-3.0.2.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\fastutil-6.5.15.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\snappy-java-1.0.5.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\guava-15.0.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\libthrift-0.9.1.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\joda-time-2.4.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\cassandra-driver-core-2.0.2.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.8.jar;C:\repository\trunk\Scala_210_wspace\Seasonality_v6\lib\apache-cassandra-clientutil-2.0.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain test
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/JEUser/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/repository/trunk/Scala_210_wspace/Seasonality_v6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: JEUser
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(JEUser)
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://spark@JEMAC17:49565]
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://spark@JEMAC17:49565]
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\JEUser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-local-20140827132310-b588
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1080.6 MB.
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 49568 with id = ConnectionManagerId(JEMAC17,49568)
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager JEMAC17:49568 with 1080.6 MB RAM
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:49569
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO broadcast.HttpBroadcast: Broadcast server started at http://169.254.179.207:49569
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is C:\Users\JEUser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-d0f66cca-8480-4932-85a6-691ee93c4fbd
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
    14/08/27 13:23:10 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:49570
    14/08/27 13:23:11 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
    14/08/27 13:23:11 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
    14/08/27 13:23:11 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://JEMAC17:4040
    14/08/27 13:23:20 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://54.183.137.105:7077...
    Got past the setup.
    Got past setting the variables.
    14/08/27 13:23:20 WARN core.FrameCompressor: Cannot find LZ4 class, you should make sure the LZ4 library is in the classpath if you intend to use it. LZ4 compression will not be available for the protocol.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 WARN core.ControlConnection: Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/172.31.7.123) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 WARN core.ControlConnection: Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/172.31.7.119) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 WARN core.ControlConnection: Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/172.31.7.120) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 WARN core.ControlConnection: Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/172.31.7.121) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 WARN core.ControlConnection: Found host with 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address, using listen_address (/172.31.7.122) to contact it instead. If this is incorrect you should avoid the use of 0.0.0.0 server side.
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /172.31.7.122:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /172.31.7.123:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /54.183.197.59:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /172.31.7.120:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /172.31.7.121:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO core.Cluster: New Cassandra host /172.31.7.119:9042 added
    14/08/27 13:23:21 INFO cql.CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: jeDev
    14/08/27 13:23:26 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.123:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.123:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
    14/08/27 13:23:26 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.122:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.122:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:241)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:42)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:273)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:265)
    14/08/27 13:23:27 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.120:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.120:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:241)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:42)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:273)
    14/08/27 13:23:36 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.120:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.120:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:241)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:42)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:273)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    14/08/27 13:23:40 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://54.183.137.105:7077...
    14/08/27 13:23:41 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.121:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.121:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:241)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:42)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:273)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    14/08/27 13:23:47 ERROR core.Session: Error creating pool to /172.31.7.119:9042
    com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.7.119:9042] Cannot connect
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.PooledConnection.<init>(PooledConnection.java:28)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:458)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.HostConnectionPool.<init>(HostConnectionPool.java:85)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.replacePool(SessionManager.java:241)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.access$400(SessionManager.java:42)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:273)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$3.call(SessionManager.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException.copy(NoHostAvailableException.java:65)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:256)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:172)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:52)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.execute(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:33)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.execute(Unknown Source)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD$$anonfun$cassandraPartitionerClassName$1.apply(CassandraRDD.scala:265)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD$$anonfun$cassandraPartitionerClassName$1.apply(CassandraRDD.scala:264)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:98)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:97)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.IOUtils$.closeAfterUse(IOUtils.scala:16)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:97)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.cassandraPartitionerClassName$lzycompute(CassandraRDD.scala:263)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.cassandraPartitionerClassName(CassandraRDD.scala:262)
        at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD.getPartitions(CassandraRDD.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:202)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1097)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:861)
        at test$.main(test.scala:26)
        at test.main(test.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.sendRequest(RequestHandler.java:103)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.execute(SessionManager.java:446)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeQuery(SessionManager.java:482)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:90)
        ... 36 more
    14/08/27 13:23:48 INFO cql.CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: jeDev
    14/08/27 13:24:00 INFO client.AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://54.183.137.105:7077...

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I need is a direction to look into.  My assumptions are threefold:
1.  I am running this from my laptop, does it need to run on the spark server directly?
2.  Do I have a jar conflict?
3.  Something more sinister, like maybe I am hitting an unknown bug?

Any help is greatly desired?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: From the log it appears that Spark has tried to connect with several of your Cassandra nodes (like 172.31.7.122:9042), but could not connect with any of them ("NoHostAvailableException"). From the laptop on which you're running this, are you sure you can reach port 9042 on those Cassandra hosts?

Comment: Unfortunately that was one of the first things that I checked.  Do you have the Spark-Cassandra-Connector working?